# Questions about Private Oblivious Transfer Protocol

Tags: oblivious-transfer

1. The receiver ***R*** chooses $a,b,r$ and computes as follows:

   If σ = 0 then $A = (g^a, g^b, g^{ab},g^r)$.

   If σ = 1 then $A = (g^a, g^b, g^r, g^{ab})$.
   ***R*** sends $A$ to ***S***.
2. Denote $(x,y,z_0,z_1)$ the tuple received by ***S***. Then, ***S*** checks that
   $(x,y,z_0,z_1)\in G$ and that $z_0 \neq z_1$. If not, it aborts outputting ⊥.

   Otherwise, ***S*** chooses random $u_0,u_1,v_0,v_1$($\in{1,2,...,q}$) and computes the following four values:

   $w_0 = x^{u_0}·g^{v_0}$,    $k_0 = {z_0}^{u_0}·y^{v_0}$

   $w_1 = x^{u_1}·g^{v_1}$,    $k_1 = {z_1}^{u_1}·y^{v_1}$

   ***S*** then encrypts $m_0$ under $k_0$ and $m_1$ under $k_1$.....

Here are my questions: Is it must necessary to choose random $u_0,u_1,v_0,v_1$, and what if  $u_0 = u_1, v_0 = v_1$, in which situation the OT protocol seems work well and property of privacy keep unchanged.